# How to back up files on windows server 2008

Tags: backup, file-transfer, windows-server-2008

how to take a back up of a folder that is more than 50Gigs and ensure that modifications to the files after commencing backup process are also reflected in the destination

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Microsoft has [Synchronization framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb902854(v=sql.110).aspx) for folders sync.
It can be easily setup with [SyncToy](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=15155) (from 2009 but still functional and available).

The difference between Synchronization framework and Robocopy is that Synchronization framework maintains metadata about the two folders inside them and thus subsequent synchronzations are perhaps a bit faster for lots of small files and there are better options for resolving conflicts.

As for robocopy, when the file is processed in a single run and then it is changed during that run, you will have to run the command again. As for  Sync framework I do not know, but perhaps too. But the changes gets synced in the next run anyway.

There is a lot of other software for this purpose:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_file_synchronization_software

Answer (score 0):

You can run ROBOCOPY with the corresponding parameters for the backup (use `ROBOCOPY /?` to see all options).

Then run the same command daily (or weekly or hourly, as you want it) with slightly altered options (look at MIRROR), to get your backup updated with all changes.